# Cannot use VGA to USB Monitor on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, wine, vga

I recently installed Ubuntu on my hp-laptop and i was planning to use this as my main workspace as my windows side has been really brutal for coding and i plan to use this until i can buy a new laptop.

my laptop specs are in the image that i attached.

each time i plug in my VGA to USB it loads up as driver and shows me a folder with a .dmg file and an .exe

i have attempted to install wine but im not sure if i did it correctly. I also tried to find a way to run the .dmg file but that also is not working.

if anyone could help me figure this out as i cant us my 3rd monitor for now until i figure this out . i would like it to run as it does on my windows side- automatically but if i can make it work the same or load an application on Ubuntu then i would be fine with that.

thanks

[Image of what shows up when i plug in VGA to USB in computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2VDL.png)

[This is a bit of information about my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KWRe.png)

Comment: A good HDMI adapter ir arguably better. USB solutions depend on DisplayLink (supported, user installable drivers) or similar chips (probably not supported). Run `lsusb` to find out, if it turns out to be DisplayLink based all you need is to install drivers. If whatever you have as drivers for Windows and Mac do not mention DisplayLink then probably it isn't (yet) supported in Linux (manufacturer doesn't provide proprietary drivers nor open sources it).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, it's seems like the manufacturer of your USB monitor doesn't support Linux. WINE will run some Windows applications but this exe file probably contains drivers written for Windows, WINE won't magically make them work with the linux kernel.
I doubt you'll get this working, but the first step is providing us with information about the VGA to USB device.

Comment: Sorry it took me a minute to find the item from my history https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07NXQSZYH?psc=1  this is it here

Comment: i took a look and it does say that it will not work for Linux, do you happen to know any ones that work for both? or maybe can i just by a HDMI splitter that works with VGA so that both my screens will just be working off of my HDMI port